# Архитектура хранения связанных данных в БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование, postgresql

На сайте предполагается возможность размещать объявления. Все объявления делятся на различные категории (грубо говоря как на Avito).
Для создания заполняется форма с полями "название", "описание" (характерно для всех объявлений) и выбор категорий. После выбора определенной категории подгружается дополнительная форма с данными (например для машин - цвет, пробег и т.д., для недвижимости - этаж, тип дома, кол-во квартир и т.д.).
Предположительно в БД будет общая таблица для всех объявлений *Adverts*:

```
id | name | description | category | type
```

в которой хранятся название, описание объявления и id категории, соответствующее категории в таблице, выбранной пользователем и поле type для разделения на более подробные таблицы с данными по объявлениям. Т.е. для каждой формы объявления есть своя таблица, например:
*Adverts*

```
23 | Продам машину | "описание" | 4 | auto
```

*AdvertAuto*

```
id | color| mileage | model
1  | red  | 280000  | honda
```

Возникает вопрос, как правильно пристыковать данные? Понятно, что в случае одного объявления достаточно просто приджоинить нужную таблицу, но что делать, когда выборка осуществляется по всем объявлениям?
Появляется необходимость джоинить сразу много таблиц в зависимости от значения поля type.
Собственно вопросы:
1) Насколько такая архитектура верная и есть ли более лучшие решения?
2) Если такая архитектура является верной, то как осуществлять выборку нескольких значений? Я видел запросы с использованием CASE - WHEN - THEN или же с JOIN UNION, но насколько эти запросы пригодны для жизни на боевом сервере?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: @u_mulder самое худшее решение, которое можно было предложить)

Comment: Аргументировать научитесь для начала.

Comment: @u_mulder Справедливости ради, хотелось бы увидеть аргументы в пользу EAV и почему это применимо для вопроса при наличии других способов решения проблемы.

Comment: @u_mulder это очень очень медленно и неподдерживаемо, никто за такую архитектуру Вам спасибо не скажет. krown_loki я предлагаю оставить всё как есть и кэшировать справочные данные, например в Redis. джойнить ничего не нужно, достаём отдельно. Читаем из кэша, если там нет достаем из базы и закидываем в кэш, при следующем запросе уже достанется с кэша, просто и удобно.

Comment: А чем не нравится просто вариант очень широкой таблицы? Повесите ключи на поля и делов. Конечно если набор характеристик в принципе переменный - то лучше воспользоваться не-реляционной БД (когда-то для почти аналогичной задачи юзали Apache Solr - pdo.ru). А если объявлений в БД планируется немного, до 5М , то подойдёт таблица `id_объявления` `id_характеристики` `значение` - с ключом и точным совпадением при поиске, нормально работать будет: для программиста с произвольным набором характеристик так презентативнее всего будет. Так как вы структуру сделали - плохо ляжет на ООП в коде.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Набор атрибутов скорее всего статичный и на раз и добавляться атрибут к какой-либо форме объявления будет скорее всего не чаще 1-2 раз в год. В связи с этим я уже склонен к варианту хранить все в 1 таблице пусть и с Null полями, мешает мне разве что только тупое убеждение себя в правильности организации БД и т.д. (только нормальная форма, вред денормализации т.д.)

Comment: @krown_loki Согласен. Правильность - понятие субъективное, а вот скорость работы и простота работы программистов с такой разработкой - объективное. Так что объективно лучше тогда широкая таблица :)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр к слову, вы упомянули о том, что такое подойдет для случая, если объявлений не более 5М. А что делать в случае, если количество объявлений таки перевалит за 5, 10, 20М ?
P.S. Вы не планируете написать ответ отдельно (не в комментах), чтобы я смог зачесть ваш ответ как решающий проблему?

Comment: @krown_loki слишком общий вопрос, давать на него развёрнутый ответ долго. Если больше 5М записей - хорошо бы пошла nosql-база данных, как говорил мы использовали solr , но есть много чего. И в общем то можно использовать и SQL - если использовать кластер БД, если оптимизировать запросы - накладывая их максимально по индексу. Зависит от того что вам больше нравится - геморрой с админством, или геморрой с малопопулярными NoSql решениями..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько способов.

1. [Entity–attribute–value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model.
   EAV позволяет в любой момент добавлять любые необходимые атрибуты без изменения схемы БД. Но работать с такой моделью довольно сложно.
2. Создавать для каждого свойства отдельный столбец. При этом всё хранится в одной таблице.
   Это подход часто используется для хранения разнотипных данных. Он вполне жизнеспособен, если данных будет не очень много (сотни тысяч строк - это немного).

   В этом случае в тех колонках, которые не относятся к описываемой сущности в данной строке, будут храниться значения `null`. На первый взгляд это может показаться неэффективно, но многие СУБД поддерживают так называемые *разреженные* (sparse) столбцы, в итоге всё становится эффективно.

   Я не спец по mysql, но поиск показывает, что в этой СУБД есть поддержка таких столбцов.
3. Использование json или xml для хранения дополнительных данных.
   Думаю, тут пояснять особо ничего не нужно. MySql поддерживает оба способа: [json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), [xml](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html).

---

В метках у вас две СУБД: mysql и postgres, из чего можно сделать вывод, что выбор БД ещё не сделан. Тогда почему бы не рассмотреть другие варианты, а именно: NoSQL?

Comment: 1) Я так понял в случае EAV - все довольно громоздко и сложно, а также непроизводительно.
2) В случае хранения в одной таблице довольно просто организовать фильтр поиска по атрибутам, но насколько затратно это будет из-за наличия Null столбцов? + содержание индексов для поиска.
3) Этот способ уберет кучу ненужных столбцов, однако как организовать фильтр поиска объявлений для такой структуры? (насколько я знаю такое возможно только в Postgresql в столбцах jsonb формата, но я никогда не работал с этим и поэтому мне сложно определиться с решением).

Comment: По поводу NoSQL, его же следует применять для вот таких отдельных случаях, весь же проект не повесить на NoSQL?

Comment: @krown_loki - ох, это холиварная тема. Теоретически можно все сделать на nosql, но практически, вероятно, лучше будет использовать и то, и то.

Answer (score 0):

1) Верная чуть менее, чем полностью, иначе у вас не возникло бы проблем с джойнами.

2.2) Это будет работать, но поддерживать, и уж тем более развивать, будет сложно.

Можно организовать так:

*categories*

```
id | name
```

*properties*

```
id | category_id | name
```

*adverts*

```
id | name | description | category_id
```

*property_values*

```
property_id | advert_id | value
```

Comment: Я так понимаю это тот же самый EAV?

Comment: Да, он самый...

Comment: Как при такой архитектуре хранения делать запрос на вывод информации по одной сущности? Я имею ввиду, что из-за большого количества атрибутов результат запросы не уложится в одну строку, как это разобрать так, чтобы можно было отобразить в виде "карточки товара" в html?
Вы сказали о проблеме с JOINами, однако при EAV в Вашем примере точно также джоинится таблица категорий, атрибутов, значений атрибутов.

Comment: Почему вам принципиально выводить информацию по одной сущности одним запросом? Вы уже в коде сущность можете собрать, только так. Нет можно конечтно 10 джоинов сделать, но их лучше вообще не делать.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр принципиально, т.к. есть возможность просматривать список объявлений с минимальной информацией (название, краткое описание + фото), так и расширенную информацию по одной сущности (объявлению), в которое входит вся информация (название, краткое описание + атрибуты конкретного объявления)

Answer (score 0):

Ваше решение приемлемо и, думаю, позволит добиться хорошей производительности. Единственная особенность, что придётся использовать динамический SQL, чтобы создавать запросы с одним JOINом. Порядок запросов такой:

1. select type from adverts where id = :id
2. результат запроса сохраняем в переменной, скажем $additional_table
3. собираем динамический sql-запрос "select a. *, b. * from adverts a join $additional_table b on a.id = b.advert_id where a.id = :id"

Последний выведет заголовки объявления и дополнительную информацию одной строкой. Время на разбор и выполнение так же должны быть минимальным по очевидным причинам. Со временем все варианты динамического запроса (варианты значений $additional_table) окажутся в кеше и ничего разбирать вообще не придётся, только выполнять.

При выборке всех объявлений не вижу смысла выводить подробные данные. Будет 40+ столбцов справа от основных данных, большинство из которых пустые. Если всё же хочется, то нужно выбрать все типы запрашиваемых объявлений, и присоединить соответствуюшие таблицы методом LEFT JOIN, т.е. повторить шаги 1-3, но в массовом порядке.

P.S. При использовании EAV карточку товара можно получить не как набор столбцов, а как набор строк, что, на мой взгляд, удобнее при формировании HTML.

P.P.S. Если поле type будет идентично названию таблицы (что подразумевается выше), то формировать вторую форму при создании объявления можно, опрашивая словарь данных.