# База данных с заголовками для полей, как лучше сделать

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица изначально из ексель файла, просто сделана через верстку, задача поместить таблицу в базу данных, и не пойму как сделать лучше, все что с заголовками разбить на отдельные таблицы, или возможно сделать одной таблицей, и добавить поля с заголовками, но как привязать например поля (см.картинку) к Шторам, Подушкам и т.д., хочется одной таблицей, посоветуйте пжлст

[image: таблица]

Comment: Зависит от конкретных задач, которые будут работать с таблицей в базе. Если задача просто нарисовать таблицу — то, может, база и не нужна вообще?

Comment: Редактирование, добавление новых полей с ценами, повышение цен на определенный процент

Comment: Если уже в процессе работы приложения действительно нужно добавлять новые поля (колонки), то см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933610/184217

Comment: Но скорее всего нужно просто задать поля "материал", "наполнитель", "размер" и этого будет достаточно.