# Класс для хранения данных из базы, в которой может меняться количество столбцов на C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity

Нужно создать класс, который будет получать и хранить данные из БД, но необходимо, чтобы можно было добавлять и удалять колонки.
Можно ли создать такой класс и как он должен выглядеть в таком случае?
Возможно, это можно сделать лишь подобным способом:

```
public class Person
{
    List<string> data;
}
```

Comment: Если меняется количество столбцов в базе - это называется миграция - медленная и нежелательная операция для базы данных. Скорее всего у вас проблема с проектированием модели данных, а не та, о которой вы говорите.  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567

Comment: [DataTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0). \ Но лучше опишите задачу подробней, зачем вам это понадобилось.

Comment: Изменять количество столбцов в таблице - не очень хорошо. Возможно, стоит задуматься над чуть иной структурой базы данных. Опишите вашу задачу чуть подробнее, чтоб была возможность было подсказать

Comment: Через программу должны вводится данные людей, есть некоторое количество точно необходимых данных, таких как ФИО, Дата рождения и др., но в 
будущем может понадобиться добавить поля, которых сейчас нет. При добавлении в приложении создается дополнительный textBox для ввода данных,
а в базе появляется колонка, в которую будет сохраняться введенное значение.

Comment: Тогда может лучше создавать новую таблицу? Создавать 1000 и 1 столбец в одной таблице не очень удобно. Добавьте идентификатор (guid или просто int) к конкретному человеку, чтобы была возможность отличить Васю от Пети. При дальнейшем развитии проекта нужно будет создать отдельную таблицу, в которой будет храниться обязательный столбец ID и другие столбцы с данными. По этому Id можно будет собирать со всей базы информацию о каком-либо человеке

Comment: @Frehzy В таком случае необходимо заполнять Id самостоятельно, ведь так? Иначе не получится при создании новой таблицы с дополнительными данными ассоциировать их с данными из исходной таблицы

Comment: @Solomon Именно. Представьте, что Id - это ссылка на какой-то объект в базе данных, по которой вы можете этот объект получить и отличить от других. Если вы выводите какую-либо таблицу в DataGridView и оттуда уже что-либо делаете с объектом, то воспользуйтесь привязками (могу оставить ссылку на материал по этой теме, если нужно). Так вам будет гораздо проще понимать, что это за объект, брать из него Id и заполнять/изменять/редактировать что-либо.

Comment: @Frehzy, хорошо, еще вопрос, а как создавать таблицы, если в приложении колонки создаются одна за другой? Неужели стоит делать таблицы с двумя полями(Id и необходимые данные) или может стоит как-то кешировать их и создавать таблицу, когда набирается несколько колонок?

Comment: @Solomon У вас постоянно создаются новый колонки через приложение? Может стоит переосмыслить архитектуру его? Даже звучит данный подход как-то странно. Вы уверены, что это правильно? Тем не менее, почему нельзя сохранять данные через какое-то время или после нажатия кнопки? Не обязательно ведь создавать по таблице с одним столбцом каждый раз

Comment: Да и вообще, можно ведь на клиенте создать шаблоны столбцов. Таким образом, заполняя какой-либо, вы будете заполнять нужную вам таблицу в БД. Итого: вы заранее создаёте нужные таблицы в БД (даже, если там будет по 2 столбца (Id и какой-то ещё)), ограничиваете на клиенте количество шаблонов, подстраивая их под таблицы в бд и сохраняете данные в конкретной (уже созданной таблице) в базе данных в соответствие с шаблоном на клиенте

Comment: @Frehzy нет, не постоянно, обычно просто данные заносятся или считываются из базы данных, но администратор приложения имеет возможность создать или удалить колонку.

Comment: В таком случае, подход с созданием таблиц и шаблонов под них идеально вписывается в ваш проект. Вам не нужно будет создавать новый столбцы, таблицы и тд. Вам не нужно будет ограничивать количество столбцов. При создании нового вам нужно определить, какой тип данных там и вставить его в соответствующую таблицу

Comment: @Frehzy Большое спасибо за ответ! А то я никак не мог определиться, как хранить и правильно работать с данными при таком подходе

Comment: Э-э-э... Вопрос у вас про класс C# с переменным количеством столбцов. А в комментариях скатились к обсуждению структуры БД. / Какая бы ни была структура БД, нужно как-то отображать её на код C#, нэ? / Напомню ещё раз: есть класс `DataTable`, который позволяет на лету добавлять/удалять колонки разных типов. / Можно использовать словарь: `Dictionary<string, object>`, где ключ - имя колонки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933610/184217 - Есть несколько распространённых способов организации данных в БД с возможностью добавления полей: EAV, широкая таблица, xml/json. | Но вопрос отображения на код C# никуда не делся.